# get pattern out of a file and grep all files associated with pattern out of a different directory

Tags: linux

I have a list of file names like this:

```
T0rain.Zfp691_0895.2_v2_deBruijn.txt
Train.Hbp1_2241.2_v2_deBruijn.txt
Train.Zfp740_0925.2_v2_deBruijn.txt
Train.Hbp1_2241.3_v1_deBruijn.txt
Train.Zfp740_0925.3_v1_deBruijn.txt
Train.Hic1_2816.2_v1_deBruijn.txt
Train.Zic1_0991.2_v1_deBruijn.txt
```

I want to extract all names between Train. and _ like this:

```
Zfp691
Hbp1
Zfp740
Hbp1
zfp740
Hic1
Zic1
```

Than i have another list of files:

```
Zfp691.pwm.txt
Hbp1.pwm.txt
Zfp740.pwm.txt
Hbp1.pwm.txt
zfp740.pwm.txt
Hic1.pwm.txt
Zic1.pwm.txt
Zic1.pwm.RC.txt
```

I want to extract all cases which match so for example:

Train.Zic1_0991.2_v1_deBruijn.txt MATCHES Zic1.pwm.txt and Zic1.pwm.RC.txt

These output arguments are passed on to my R script. So the `SH` script should give back the arguments =

```
$i (Train.Zic1_0991.2_v1_deBruijn.txt) +  $j Zic1.pwm.txt
$i (Train.Zic1_0991.2_v1_deBruijn.txt) +  $j Zic1.pwm.RC.txt
```

I don’t know if this is even possible. I started trying with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in input/*/testtrain/Train*deBruijn.txt
do
    $i 
done

for j in input/All_PWMs/*/*.txt
do
    $j 
done

echo qsub script3.sh $i $j
```

Here i try to give the arguments to script3.sh but this only give 1 combination back. Anyone a hint or a tip?? like how to match/grep the names. Or a different way of passing through arguments.

Script3.sh is for invoking R in linux command line. So the args are just passed through this file to invoke a single R job with 1 combination of debruijn and pwm.

The r script needs 1 debruijn.txt and 1 pwm.txt to be able to calculate the values i need.
So for this example i will get 2 combinations:

```
debruijn.txt and pwm1.txt   -----> pass the args to R as combination 1
debruijn.txt and pwm2.txt   -----> pass the args to R as combination 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@files=glob("*.*_*");

foreach $f (@files) {
  $f =~ /^[^\.]+\.([^_]+)_/;
  $pre = $1;
  @f2 = glob ("$1*");
  print "$f found files ".join(" ",@f2)."\n";
  system ("./script.sh",$f,@f2) && die ($!);
}
```

Gives output:

```
T0rain.Zfp691_0895.2_v2_deBruijn.txt found files Zfp691.pwm.txt
Train.Hbp1_2241.2_v2_deBruijn.txt found files Hbp1.pwm.txt
Train.Hbp1_2241.3_v1_deBruijn.txt found files Hbp1.pwm.txt
Train.Hic1_2816.2_v1_deBruijn.txt found files Hic1.pwm.txt
Train.Zfp740_0925.2_v2_deBruijn.txt found files Zfp740.pwm.txt
Train.Zfp740_0925.3_v1_deBruijn.txt found files Zfp740.pwm.txt
Train.Zic1_0991.2_v1_deBruijn.txt found files Zic1.pwm.RC.txt Zic1.pwm.txt
```

My "script.sh" is:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Script got $0 $1 $2 $3
```

Make sure you chmod 755 all the scripts, etc.

Comment: i tried to apply this to my data but how will i be able to pass on 2 args. $f and `@f2` cannot be passed to my other script. Or is the second argument different than `@f2`

Comment: so if im correct "script" will be my other script name>>?? and than the combinations can be used there?

Comment: Yes. (Don't forget you might need a ./script or other path components.

Comment: i tried to make it work, but i cant seem to pass on the args to my other script. I did it like this: `system ("./script3.sh",$f,@f2);` My script3 is in the same directory as the script from my question.
Maybe its nice to know that i try to run the scripts on a cluster

Comment: See my revised answer. I added how I am doing the system call, and the script I am calling. If the call to run the script fails, it should tell you why.